Wix 5 setup fails during installation with error message in log "Error 0x80070001: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0"
We've upgraded to Wix 5 a setup developed using Wix 3. When built using Visual Studio, the setup works fine. However, the setup built on our CI system fails to display.
The error log contains
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]i001: Burn x86 v5.0.1+2f00cbe680fb01ab485d56f16de9cd19b133f875, Windows v10.0 x64 (Build 22631: Service Pack 0), path: F:\work\setup.exe
[07B0:3FF0][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to wait for operation complete.
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container.
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open attached container.
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open attached UX container.
[07B0:7808][2024-11-01T13:43:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to initialize core.
We do use Insignia.exe to sign the WixEngine.exe file.
We've checked the digital signatures for the .MSI file, the WixEngine.exe file and the setup.exe file, and they are all right.
Can you give us a hint how to continue troubleshooting?

Insignia doesn't exist in WiX v5. If you're still using it, you're probably corrupting your bundle. Read the documentation on how to sign bundles correctly..

Thank you, Rob! We've implemented the changes in our build script, as described in the documentation, but the error persists.

It seems the error is from the build, not from the signing process. The unsigned file has the same behaviour.
